Direct Retrieval of Nearest Location Using OSRM Nearest API
I've been using the OSRM Nearest API service to obtain the nearest nodes within a road network. However, the response only provides the node IDs, not the actual locations. To retrieve the locations, I have to reference the node IDs from the PBF file. Is there a way to directly obtain the nearest location?
Neareset API Call
{
    "code": "Ok",
    "waypoints": [
        {
            "hint": "hM4bgP___384AAAAOgAAABEAAAAAAAAAP3F9QpEJoz-9bJVBAAAAADgAAAA6AAAAEQAAAAAAAABTCgEAaxzOAFQRIgN0HM4ATBEiAwEA3w4cClna",
            "nodes": [
                30690709,
                1841273491
            ],
            "distance": 1.07925309,
            "name": "Falkenberger Chaussee",
            "location": [
                13.507691,
                52.564308
            ]
        }
    ]
}

